# How to prevent error "Id: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Id' is already defined."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In order to implement a custom authentication module, I have used asp.net Identity. And I need my User class to inherit from asp.net Identity's User class. I have two fields with the same name, but different value types, and of course I get an error. Please tell me what I need to do to prevent this error. It will be very appreciated.

```
// asp.net Identity User class
public class User : Entities.User, IUser
{
    public new string Id
    {
        get { return base.Id.ToString(); }
    }
}

// My User class   
public class Entities.User : BaseDomainObject
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseDomainObject
{
    public BaseDomainObject()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Change the name of the string.  you don't really have another choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `IUser` interface, rather use the generic `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<int>`, this way you don't need to change the type of `Id`

```
public class User : Entities.User, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<int> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have 2 properties with same name even if they have different types.

If you need that thing this is for sure a design issue, may be you need to think again about what business scenario you need to cover and look for a different design/solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your design so that User doesn't inherit from Entities.User.

If need a reference to the Entities.User object, you could store it as a property on User:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    private Entities.User _eUser;
    public Entities.User EUser
    {
        get { return _eUser; }
        set { _eUser = value; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _eUser.Id.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance